# xcode 13.2 landscape design for storyboard in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface, storyboard

can anyone help me how to design landscape UI design in iphone and ipad for xcode 13. previously xcode versions we have an option like Vary for Traits directly. in current version no option for vary for traits.

Comment: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/xcode-13-vary-for-traits/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add constraints variations here:

[image]